# csvreader longtable caption repeated on every page

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, csv, csvsimple

I am using `csvreader` with `longtable` and I added a caption in `table head` below is my code:

```
\csvreader[
  longtable=ccc,
  table head=\caption{Caption goes here.
}\label{tab:sometab} \\
    \toprule\bfseries id &\bfseries gene &\bfseries name \\ \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot,
  late after line=\\,
]{app/fsnewtax.csv}{1=\id,2=\gene,3=\name}{\id&\gene&\name}
```

This is part of the csv file:

```
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
```

The problem is: the caption is repeated on every page of the table, I want it to be just on the first page. How to do this ? I couldn't find anything related to adding caption in the `csvsimple` documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is very simple to solve, just use `\endfirsthead` after what you want on the first page and `\endhead` after what you want on the following pages. See [`longtable` package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf).

I repeated your data many times in the `fsnewtax.csv` of my MWE to have a table two page long.

Moreover, I put the label inside the caption description without going to a new line, otherwise the caption is not correctly centered.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{fsnewtax.csv}
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
23271,cox3,Poec
685,cox3,Pier
5,atp6,Luc
85,atp6,Mut
16,nad3,Ans
55,nad3,Ple
13,nad3,Geo
\end{filecontents*} 
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document} 
\csvreader[
  longtable=ccc,
  table head=\caption{Caption goes here.\label{tab:sometab}}\\
    \toprule\bfseries id &\bfseries gene &\bfseries name \\ \midrule\endfirsthead
    \toprule\bfseries id &\bfseries gene &\bfseries name \\ \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot,
  late after line=\\,
]{fsnewtax.csv}{1=\id,2=\gene,3=\name}{\id&\gene&\name}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]